# Convert text(font) to ABGR buffer

Tags: c++, text

The purpose is to provide a text image buffer to the exe as a DLL (c++).

The detailed purpose is as follows.

Since exe was made with "GameMakerStudio (hereinafter GMS)", it does not support various fonts.
I thought of a way to solve this.
GMS (exe) provides a pointer to the buffer (data) and text to be stored in the DLL.
DLL converts text into RGBA buffer (data) using Windows default font (or set font) and saves it in pointer location.
(Of course, DLL provides horizontal and vertical size to GMS (exe).)
I can do the rest of the process, but I'm not sure how to convert the text to an RGBA buffer (data).

So I would like to get some advice on how to convert text (utf8) to RGBA buffer (data).
-I want to support utf8.
-I wish I could change the font.

The converted data looks like the following.
ABGR ABGR ABGR .... ABGR
(ABGR -> 4 bytes)

For example, if the text'ABC' looks like the image below,

[ABC image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XlRG.png)

The DLL converts to RGBA buffer (data) and stores it in a pointer as shown below.

```
FFFFFFFF FF0000FF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FFFFFFFF FF0000FF FFFFFFFF FF0000FF FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FF0000FF FF0000FF FF0000FF FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FF0000FF FFFFFFFF FF0000FF FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FF0000FF FFFFFFFF FF0000FF FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FFFFFFFF
```

I got help from Google Translator.
I don't know if my intentions were conveyed properly.

Comment: Are you simply asking how to render text with a given font to a bitmap? See if you cannot get [stb_truetype.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_truetype.h) to work, or else go for a full [Freetype](https://www.freetype.org/) approach.

Comment: As @Botje indicates, an ABGR buffer is a buffer of pixels, where each pixel is constructed out of 4 values: alpha, blue, green and red for the pixel. There can be multiple formats (i.e. 4x8bit = 32bit, 64bit etc..). The step you are missing is to 'convert' or render each character from a font as a number of pixels. FreeType is a heavy library, you can probably get away with more lightweight font libraries such as stb, libschrift or fontstash.

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved it.